# External monitor dont work on Lenovo ThinkPad with AMD Ryzen 5700u

Tags: thinkpad, external-monitor, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I just installed the newest Ubuntu on  laptop ThinkPad E15 Gen3 with Radeon GPU on Ryzen5700u and found a big problem - external monitor is not working...

I dont even see in dmesg anything about trying to connect via HDMI.

Is there any chance how to get IT  work? I Tried offical amdgpu drivers and third party ones - ppa:oibaf. No luck...

Comment: Ubuntu already comes with open-source AMD graphics drivers and they DO work perfectly fine, including for external monitors. Have you tried before installing what you likely shouldn't?

Comment: Yes, before i tried anything else, but it didnt detected connected HDMI, with another laptop it worked fine.. with the same cable and monitor.

Comment: Check UEFI settings, maybe something is disabled there.